# How can I show in a select values that have the ID that I get from the controller?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a select controlled by Thymeleaf

```
<select th:field="*{customer}">
   <option th:each="customer: ${customers}" th:value="${customer.id}" th:text="${customer.name}"></option>
</select>
```

This select show me all the customers of the DB.

How can I show just the customer with the ID that I get from here:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addRoute(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("route", new RouteCommand());

    /*User userAux = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    model.addAttribute("customer", userAux.getCustomer().getId());*/

    return "admin/routes/add";
}
```

The code that is commented get the ID of the value that I want to show in the select.

Comment: What do you mean "show just the customer with the ID"? Isn't that exactly what you have rigth now? Or do you only want to pass the CustomerID to the Model? Or do you only want to show exactly one customer?

Comment: I want to show in the select just the customer that belongs to the user that is loged in. It can be just one. But in the select show me all the customers of the DB. My idea is to show just the name of the customer user, exactly one customer

Comment: instead of passing customer object, just send ID you want to display ,from controller and read it in html, paste more code if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure below works but you can try as I do not have a workspace to test the solution and also I assume you are using Spring Security Tag and user is logged in

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.customer.id" var="cId" scope="page" />

<select th:field="*{customer}">
       <option th:each="customer: ${customers.?[id == __${cId}__]}" th:value="${customer.id}" th:text="${customer.name}"></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ;D